# generate array element if not exists in python

Tags: python

What is the right way to check if element does not exist in Python ?
The element is expected to be present most of the time, and if it is empty it is not an "error" and need to be processed normally:

```
def checkElement(self, x, y):
    if not (self.map[x][y]):
        self.map[x][y] = 'element {}:{}'.format(x, y)

    return self.map[x][y]
```

Comment: What kind of data structure is `self.map`?

Comment: Since you've got `x` and `y`, check the boundaries of `self.map`. Or initialize it with `None` beforehand.

Comment: Good question: Is it a list containing lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Best way to check if any object (Lists, Dicts, etc) exist or not is to wrap it within a `try...except` Block. Your `checkElement` Function could be re-written thus:

```
def checkElement
    try:
         self.map[x][y]
    except:
         # HANDLE THE CASE WHERE self.map[x][y] ISN'T SET...
         self.map[x][y] = 'element {}:{}'.format(x, y)
```

Comment: This confuse me a bit as I am new to Python. The empty element is "expected" part of this function workflow ... flagging it as exception seems a bit strange.

Comment: @d.raev Sure! But in actuality, this has nothing to do with any real Exception. Observe that the Snippet above wasn't pointing to any `Type of Exception` Specifically... This is because this is just somehow a Workaround for something that does not exist in Python. In a language like PHP, a simple call to `isset($variable)` will do this perfectly....

Answer (score 2):

### tldr

Your own code together with triplee's answer cover the common cases. I want to point out ambiguity in your question. How you check for "*empty*" very much depends on what your definition of empty is.

---

This is a tricky question because the semantics of "empty" are not exactly clear. Assuming that the data structure is a nested `dict` as could be inferred from your example, then it could be the case that empty means *the inner/outer key is not contained in the dictionary*. In that case you'd want to go with what triplee suggests. Similarly if the container is a nested list, but instead of `KeyError` you'd catch `IndexError`.

Alternatively, it could also be the case that "*empty*" means both the inner and outer keys *are* in the dictionary (or list) but the value at that position is some signifier for "*empty*". In this case the most natural "empty" in Python would be `None`, so you'd want to check if the value under those keys is `None`. `None` evaluates to `False` in boolean expressions so your code would work just fine.

However, depending on how *your application* defines empty these are not the only alternatives. If you're loading json data *and* the producer of said json has been prudent, empty values are `null` in json and map to `None` when loaded into Python. More often than not the producer of the json has not been prudent and empty values are actually just empty strings `{firstName:''}`, this happens more often than one would like. It turns out that `if not self.map[x][y]` works in this case as well because an empty string also evaluates to `False`, same applies to an empty `list`, an empty `set` and an empty `dict`.

We can generalise the meaning of empty further and say that "empty" is any value that is not recognised as actionable or valid content by the application and should therefore be considered "*empty*" - but you can already see how this is completely dependent on what the application is. Would `{firstName: ' '}` a string that only contains white space be empty, is a partially filled in email address empty?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to what you *seem* to be asking is simply

```
try:
    result = self.map[x][y]
except KeyError:
    result = 'element {}:{}'.format(x, y)
    self.map[x][y] = result
return result
```

Of course, if `self.map[x]` might also not exist, you have to apply something similar to that; or perhaps redefine it to be a `defaultdict()` instead, or perhaps something else entirely, depending on what sort of structure this is.

`KeyError` makes sense for a dict; if `self[x]` is a list, probably trap `IndexError` instead.

Comment: This makes some broad assumptions about the structure of `self.map`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Added some caveats.